# TemplateField ItemTemplate only showing after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, itemtemplate, templatefield

I'm creating a GridView dynamically in the code behind for a variable row/columns GirdView. Each cell contains 1 or 2 DropDownLists. I have verified that all the code is being hit as expected, however on the initial page load none of the DropDownLists appear. They only appear after I make adjustments in other controls causing a postback, and then all DropDownLists appear as expected.

Any suggestions as to where my issue could be?

Comment: We are missing your code, sorry

Comment: I deliberately didn't post any code, as the issue could have been in multiple places and I was unsure what someone would need to look at.

But while I was still working on it, I actually just fixed it.

I was only running the method that manipulated the grid on load, and drop down changes, so it didn't trigger on an unrelated post back.

I now call that on all post backs and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that my gridview manipulation was only happening during initial load, and specific events, not all post backs.

I added the gridview manipulation to all loads and it works.